# dropdownlist selectedvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used a webservice to create a dropdownlist of countries and I'm trying to add the dropdownlist selection to the sql database, but when I do that by using ddlCountry.SelectedValue in my insert statement, only the first value in the dropdownlist is showing up in the table. Should I use onselectedindexchanged to somehow store the value? What code should I be using?

Comment: Are you sure that first value is not the one that is selected when you are executing code that save in to DB? If you want to save into DB as soon as the selection changes, then you should do that inside selection change event

Comment: try showing your code please ^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're not repopulating your dropdown from the web service on a postback.  That will cancel out your selection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are firing some sort of save function on button click's even then you can go ahead with ddl.SelectedItem.Text (if you wan't to store the text in your table) if you want to store the value part of the country list then go ahead with ddl.SelectedItem.Value

SelectedIndexChanged should be only used if you want to perform some action at the time when user selects an item in the drop down